# Que veut dire "Sous réserve d'accréditation"?

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Je suis en Licence 3 à la fac et en voulant postuler pour un master il y avait d'écrit "Sous réserve d'accréditation". Mais je n'en comprends pas le sens.

D'avance merci.

Comment: Simplement le master en question n'a pas encore recu son accreditation et donc son existence ne peut etre 100% guaranti.

Comment: "*sous réserve de [thing]*" means "provided [thing]", "at the condition there is [thing]"

Answer (score 2):

« Sous réserve de X » signifie à peu près « à condition que X arrive », « sauf si X est refusé ». X est toujours un évènement futur. C'est du langage administratif.

Par exemple, si un cours pour un diplôme est indiqué comme « sous réserve d'accréditation », cela signifie que le diplôme n'a pas encore reçu l'[accréditation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accr%C3%A9ditation) du gouvernement, c'est-à-dire qu'il n'est pas encore reconnu officiellement comme un diplôme. L'université propose déjà l'inscription aux cours parce qu'elle pense que le diplôme sera accrédité avant que les étudiants passent l'examen, mais elle avertit qu'il n'est pas encore sûr que le diplôme soit reconnu.

On peut aussi dire « sous réserve que le diplôme soit accrédité », mais en langage administratif on utilise plutôt la formulation avec un nom « sous réserve d'accréditation [du diplôme] ».